# Command Get-ADUser -Filter doesn't work in PSSession

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-remoting

I'm doing a script for changing user account AD with a GUI.
When selecting a user in a list, I want to show all the groups of which he is a member.
For the order it is OK but in a PSSession the command does not work, the `-Filter` parameter does not recognize the variable

```
$SessionAD = New-PSSession -ComputerName $AD
Invoke-Command $SessionAD -Command {Import-Module ActiveDirectory}
Import-PSSession $SessionAD -Module ActiveDirectory

...

$var = $ListeUsers.SelectedItem
$GroupsMember = Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -like $var} -Property MemberOf |
                Select -ExpandProperty MemberOf |
                Get-ADGroup -Property MemberOf |
                Select Name
```

```
Error : La variable : « var » trouvée dans l’expression : $var n’est pas définie.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument : (:) [Get-ADUser], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : La variable : « var » trouvée dans l’expression : $var n’est pas définie.,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
    + PSComputerName        : AD-01
```

With the code below the command runs fine, but I can not retrieve the values of the variable `$GroupsMember`:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $SessionAD -ArgumentList $var,$GroupsMember -ScriptBlock {
    Param($var, $GroupsMember)
    $GroupsMember = Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -like $var} -Property MemberOf |
                    Select -ExpandProperty MemberOf |
                    Get-ADGroup -Property MemberOf |
                    Select Name
}
```

Comment: Hi, Maybe the $var is not created in the same session as the one loaded after Import-PSSession. Could you type get-variable after $var = $ListeUsers.SelectedItem ?

Comment: The variable is in the same pssession.

With Get-Variable there is this error:

Get-Variable : Impossible de trouver une variable nommée « test05 ».
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 8
+ $var | Get-Variable
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (test05:String) [Get-Variable], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetVariableCommand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a solution to your problem. 
In your code the braces in `Get-ADuser -Filter{...}` are the problem.

you can update your code like that :

```
$SessionAD = New-PSSession -ComputerName "SVADDS01.Mylab.local"
Invoke-Command $SessionAD -Command {Import-Module ActiveDirectory}
Import-PSSession $SessionAD -Module ActiveDirectory | Out-Null

$ADUSers = Get-ADuser -Filter *
$var = $ADUSers | Select-Object -Property Name, SamaccountName | Out-GridView -OutputMode Single 

$GroupsMember = Get-ADUser -Filter ('Name -eq "' + $var.Name + '"') -Property MemberOf |
                Select -ExpandProperty MemberOf |
                Get-ADGroup -Property MemberOf |
                Select Name

$GroupsMember
Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
```

Note that in the current solution :

- My $var object contains an instance of a Get-ADUser object. this is the reason why I'm using $var.Name in the search
- the Get-ADUser use, like you, a Filter but this one is a String built from the previous selection

Comment: Thank's , your solution works but I do not want to go through gridview but by a user list "combobox" in a GUI. The variable that contains the selected user is $ var

Comment: It's not a problem. I used OUt-gridview in order to make some tests; but in your situation you can use combobox.SelectedItem or combobox.selectedValue. Show me your code and i'll be able to give you the right filter syntax.

Comment: $ADUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter "*" -SearchBase "OU=Users,DC=digital,DC=local" | Select Name,SamAccountName | Sort-Object Name
Foreach ($Users in $ADUsers)
    {$ListUsers.Items.Add($Users.Name)
    }

$BtnUpdate.add_click({
$SelectedUser = $ListUsers.SelectedItem
$ADGroupsMember = Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -like $SelectedUser} -Property MemberOf | Select -ExpandProperty MemberOf | Get-ADGroup -Property MemberOf | Select Name
Foreach ($Groups in $ADGroupsMember)
    {$ListADGroupsMember.Items.Add($Groups.Name)}
})

Comment: Sorry I can not answer with the layout :s Thank you !

Comment: ... $ADGroupsMember = Get-ADUser -Filter ('Name -eq "' + $SelectedUser.Name + '"') -Property MemberOf ...

Comment: It works !! Thank you very much ! I did not know this syntax. I will study it

Comment: You're welcome ;-) Could you mark the answer as solution please ? thank you